# help with inotify C script

Tags: c, linux, directory, buffer, inotify

[Source](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-ubuntu-inotify/index.html)

I've never used C before. this script adds a listener onto a directory and notifies the user by echoing to the terminal and then exiting whenever a file event happens. I want to modify the script to NOT exit but instead continuing monitoring the folder. I think the key might be this line:

`length = read( fd, buffer, BUF_LEN );`

but I don't really understand what is going on here. The description of the `read()` function is probably helpful for those who know C really well:

`Using inotify is simple: Create a file descriptor, attach one or more watches (a watch is a path and set of events), and use the read() method to receive event information from the descriptor. Rather than burn scarce cycles, read() blocks until events occur.`

but I don't fall into that category.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The program exists simply because nothing stops it from getting to `exit( 0 );` once it has caught an event. You could wrap everything from `fd = inotify_init();` to `( void ) close( fd );` in a loop and it will start over as long as you want it to.

The problem isn't in `length = read( fd, buffer, BUF_LEN );`. That part just waits for an event to happen and it doesn't call for the program to exit. It's really that the `main` is designed to be executed in one run-through and exit.

Comment: right. so what confused me about that was `while ( i < length )` is the loop condition where `length` is the variable mentioned in the `read()` call. why is a "length" used for the output of `read()`?

Comment: `read()` reads directly into `buffer` and returns the number of bytes read, which is stored in `length`. I'm not entirely sure what the `while ( i < length )` condition is, but with each loop `i` is incremented by the length of an event so I assume the program can catch simultaneous events and the loop reads them all? I'm no C guru either so that's just my guess.

Comment: That's correct.  inotify can queue multiple events and then a `read()` will return them.  The `while (i < length)` loop checks the result of one such `inotify` invocation.  To do what the OP wants, he needs another (infinite) loop right before `length = read( fd, buffer, BUF_LEN );` and continuing till the end of the `while ( i < length )` loop (and a `break` for `length < 0` case).